# Ternary association with a composite primary key (JPA & Hibernate )

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make a ternary association with a composite primary key of 3 keys that reference 3 tables : REPORT, SCANNER and RISK , I have tried to implemente this using the code below, but I have a composite key with only 2 keys : riskId and reportId :

Report.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REPORT")
public class Report {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue  
    private int reportId;

    @Column
    private String reportName;

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyJoinColumn
    Map<Risk, Scanner> risks = new HashMap<Risk, Scanner>();
}
```

Scanner.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SCANNER")
public class Scanner{
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue  
    private int scannerId;

    @Column
    private String scannerName; 
}
```

Risk.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RISK")
public class Risk {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    private int riskId;

    @Column
    private String issueName;
}
```

So how to implemente a composite primary key with 3 keys ?

Comment: refer to link `http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177`

Comment: I also try to specify the other two columns in Report.java, but it doesn't work @MapKeyJoinColumns({@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="riskId"),@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="scannerId")})